# How to Extract lines between pattern using java pattern?

Tags: java, regex, string

Trying to extract the lines between two pattern (tags) using java , By storing the values in variable I can able to do that.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RunExampleTest{

    private Pattern addressPattern = Pattern.compile(ADDRESS_PATTERN);
    private Matcher matcher;

    //Alternative
    /*private Pattern addressPattern =
        Pattern.compile(ADDRESS_PATTERN, Pattern.DOTALL);*/

    private static final String ADDRESS_PATTERN = "(?s)Address 1:\\s(.*)Address 2:";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String data = "Testing... \n" +
            "Address 1: 88 app 2/8\n" +
            "superman taman, puchong\n" +
            "36100, Malaysia\n" +
            "Address 2: abc" +
            "testing end";

        RunExampleTest obj = new RunExampleTest();
        List<String> list = obj.getAddress(data);

        System.out.println("Test Data : ");
        System.out.println(data + "\n");

        System.out.println("Address Resut : " + list);

    }

    private List<String> getAddress(String data){

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        matcher = addressPattern.matcher(data);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            result.add(matcher.group(1));
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

but instead of reading from variable I need to get data between the start and end pattern from file.

example input file:

```
Address 1: xyz 
89/23
Pin -12
Address 2: abc address
Address 1: xyz 
89/23
Pin -12
Address 2: abc address
```

Used the below,

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

        matcher = addressPattern.matcher(line);

            while( matcher.find())
            {
                System.out.println(line);   
            }
        }
```

output file :

```
xyz 
89/23
Pin -12
xyz 
89/23
Pin -12
```

Tried reading line by line but doesn't help. Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your current attempt(s).

1. The groups in the `Matcher` are indexed from one, not zero.  So `group(1)` will give you the value *before* the `Address 1" marker.
2. If you need to use `find` repeatedly on the same string<sup>1</sup>, you are using the wrong overload of `find`.  That overload starts looking for a match at the start of the string.  You need the overload that takes an offset to start searching from.  The logic would be something like this:

   ```
   start <- 0
   while ( matcher.find(start) ) {
       ...
       start <- matcher.end(0)
   }
   ```

---

<sup>1 - I'm not convinced that you are, but I'm not entirely sure that I understand your task.  Does the input consist on one record or multiple records?</sup>

Comment: I am trying to read a file with i.e unstructured data. Need to extract in between to based on start tag (Address 1:) and end tag (Address 2:) from file which is of multiline.

Comment: I'd already figured that out.  What I can't figure out is whether, (and I quote) *"the input consist[s] on one record or multiple records"*.

Comment: multiple records.

Comment: In that case, you need something that is based on my pseudocode ... or something that parses in a more intelligent fashion than you can do with a regex.